# Drop chart according to parameter in birt report

Tags: parameters, charts, birt

Here i come up with two problem 
1) i had two data-set,two chart and two parameter so now am trying to drop chart according to parameter for example::if i select params["Geography"].value second chart have to drop  and if i select params["outlet"].value first chart have to drop so i wrote script in before factory  but its not work any wrong in this

```
outname = reportContext.getReportRunnable().designHandle.getDesignHandle().findElement("out");
geoname = reportContext.getReportRunnable().designHandle.getDesignHandle().findElement("geo");

if (params["Geography"].value)
{
outname.drop();
}
else
{
geoname.drop();
}
```

2)while am selecting parameter value passing to chart but some time am getting error like so how to check and stop this error

```
The following items have errors:

Chart (id = 2736):
- TypeError: Cannot call method "getSeriesIdentifier" of null at line 43 of chart script:''
exception.javascript.error ( 1 time(s) )
detail : org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: TypeError: Cannot call method "getSeriesIdentifier" of null at line 43 of chart script:''
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.processExtendedContent(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:1097)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.localizeForeign(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.localize(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask$PageRangeRender.render(RenderTask.java:718)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.renderReport(ReportEngineService.java:1555)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.getPage(BirtViewerReportService.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtChangeParameterActionHandler.doRenderPage(BirtChangeParameterActionHandler.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractChangeParameterActionHandler.__execute(AbstractChangeParameterActionHandler.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleChangeParameter(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor194.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor136.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(ServletManager.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:953)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1014)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.chart.exception.ChartException: TypeError: Cannot call method "getSeriesIdentifier" of null at line 43 of chart script:''
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.script.AbstractScriptHandler.convertException(AbstractScriptHandler.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.script.AbstractScriptHandler.callJavaScriptFunction(AbstractScriptHandler.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.script.AbstractScriptHandler.callFunction(AbstractScriptHandler.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.render.AxesRenderer.renderPlot(AxesRenderer.java:2308)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.render.AxesRenderer.render(AxesRenderer.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.factory.Generator.render(Generator.java:1382)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.renderToImageFile(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:1128)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.generateRenderObject(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:979)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.onRowSets(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationProxy.onRowSets(ChartReportItemPresentationProxy.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.processExtendedContent(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:1074)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "getSeriesIdentifier" of null (/report/body/extended-item[@id="2736"]/method[@name="onRender"]#43)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3654)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3632)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3660)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3679)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefCallError(ScriptRuntime.java:3698)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2221)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2214)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:117)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c980._c2(/report/body/extended-item[@id="2736"]/method[@name="onRender"]:43)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c980.call(/report/body/extended-item[@id="2736"]/method[@name="onRender"])
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:398)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3065)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c980.call(/report/body/extended-item[@id="2736"]/method[@name="onRender"])
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.script.AbstractScriptHandler.callJavaScriptFunction(AbstractScriptHandler.java:370)
    ... 74 more
```

Answer (score 0):

1)Your script in beforeFactory is fine, the exception is not related to it. Your charts are not correctly dropped for one of these reasons:

1-names "out" and "geo" are not set in your design

2-your parameter Geography is not a boolean datatype. May be you have forgotten to test a value, something like:

```
if (params["Geography"].value=="geo")
{
outname.drop();
}
else
{
geoname.drop();
}
```

2) The error occurs in  some javascript code attached to the chart:

In Eclipse designer select the chart => script tab, at line 43 you should see the code invoking "getSeriesIdentifier" method.

Most likely, depending on your input parameters the chart sometimes returns no data, therefore the object invoking getSeriesIdentifier is not defined.

To solve the problem, check if this object != null before using it.

Comment: i have tried but its not working..let u consider that am having five listbox parameter  like A,B,C,D,E so now am trying to show a chart for  A,C,D,E parameter in one chart and in the same report am  trying to show another chart  for this parameter like B,C,D,E so now according to parameter to that how to drop the chart or we can use visibility for this ..any idea for this ???

Comment: for second question i did't use any java script or scripting to chart then also error is occurring how to avoid to it??